# Httpclient.GetStringAsync works in UWP and iOS, but not Android on Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am really stuck on this. I upgraded my Xamarin Forms project to .NET Standard from PCL, and this code below no longer works on Android. I have my Android settings for HttpClient implementation of Android and SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS 1.2+. In particular, when I am debugging, and I try to step over the line with httpClient.GetStringAsync … it blows up with Frame not in module (The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location). And it returns back to the caller. The try / catch does not catch and error. I can step thru this code fine in UWP/ iOS. I have been stuck on this for a while now. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I have tried wrapping the httpclient with a using statement and get the same results too. All of my NuGet packages are up to date. I am running on actual device running Android version 8.1.0, not emulator, to an actual service, not localhost.
Here is my code:
:

```
        private async Task<List<string>> GetVideoIdsFromPlaylistAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var videoIds = new List<string>();
            try
            {
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(apiUrlForPlaylist).ConfigureAwait(false);
                JObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                var items = response.Value<JArray>("items");
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    videoIds.Add(item.Value<JObject>("contentDetails")?.Value<string>("videoId"));
                };
                YoutubeItems = await GetVideosDetailsAsync(videoIds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"     Error {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(@"     Error {0}", ex.InnerException?.Message);
            }
            return videoIds;
        }
```

Comment: try to change the **HttpClient implementation** to **Managed** and **SSL/TLS implementation** to **Native TLS 1.2+**

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thanks, but got the same results. However, after waiting a bit, the try catch caught an error this time. Task was canceled. I am starting to think  there is some blocking going on in the UI thread for Android. I was able to recreate this error in a code behind page in addition my original ViewModel. I will start researching that next.

Comment: what error it throw ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Nothing is wrong with the code. I was looking at this post https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88370/httpclient-getasync-throws-task-was-cancelled-exception and it got me  thinking to try a few things.  I was getting a timeout error if I let this run long enough ( 1 to 2 minutes). I tried my hotspot on my phone for wifi instead of my home wifi, and it works. So, I rebooted the cable modem and it works as expected. Go figure?